# Batch file - How to use FindStr with percent

Tags: batch-file, registry, environment-variables, findstr

I have a batch file with the following header:

```
@Echo off
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion EnableExtensions
```

Within a `If` statement, enclosed in parenthesis `()`, I have the following code:

```
Echo SOME_VAR|FindStr /r /C:"^.*SOME.*$"
Echo Error: !errorlevel!
Echo %%SOME_VAR%%|FindStr /r /C:"^.*SOME.*$"
Echo Error: !errorlevel!
```

This will print:

```
SOME_VAR
Error: 0
Error: 1
```

If SOME_VAR is an existing environment variable, this is what I get. If I delete the variable, I get the expected success.

What happens here? Do I need to escape something more? How can I get a successful find on the 2nd one if the variable exists? I'm only interested in doing a text search where the searched text contains the `%` character and happens to match an existing variable name.

By the way, the source for the comparison will eventually be a variable too, in which I've loaded the PATH as read from the Windows Registry. So eventually, the string I am searching for will become `/C:"^.%%SOME_VAR%%;.*$"`

My PATH variable looks like this:

```
%SOME_VAR%;C:\Windows\system32...................etc
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is another layer of escape required because each side of the pipe is executed via `CMD /C` with a command line context, not a batch context. The initial batch parser transforms `%%SOME_VAR%%` to `%SOME_VAR%`. The command line parser then leaves `%SOME_VAR%` as is if the variable is undefined. We need to prevent the expansion if the variable is defined. Doubling the percents does not work in a command line context. The solution is to insert a disappearing caret somewhere between the percents, like `%^SOME_VAR%`. The caret is treated as part of the variable name, so it prevents expansion of the variable (unless you have a variable named `^SOME_VAR`). After failed expansion, the caret is consumed by the normal escape process. The caret must be escaped so that the batch parser passes the caret to the `CMD /C` command line context.

The final batch line becomes:

```
Echo %%^^SOME_VAR%% | FindStr SOME_VAR
```

Note: I simplified the FINDSTR command into a much simpler, but equivalent search.

When you modify the search on the right to include the percents, you will need to insert the escaped caret as well.

**Update in response to question in comment**
The following code demonstrates some possible ways to work with variables:

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion

:: Put both the text you want to search, as well as the search itself, in variables
set "text=%%SOME_VAR%%;C:\Windows\system32...................etc"
set "search=%%SOME_VAR%%"
echo text=%text%
echo search=%search%
echo(

echo(
echo Starting with delayed expansion disabled
echo -----------------------------------------
echo(

:: Use delayed expansion to safely expand any variable without worrying about content.
:: Both sides of the pipe are executed in a command line context with delayed expansion disabled.
:: You must use CMD /V:ON to enable delayed expansion within the pipe.

echo Test when SOME_VAR is undefined:
set "SOME_VAR="
if 1==1 (
  cmd /v:on /c echo !text!|cmd /v:on /c findstr "!search!"
)
echo(

echo Test when SOME_VAR is defined:
set "SOME_VAR=DEFINED"
if 1==1 (
  cmd /v:on /c echo !text!|cmd /v:on /c findstr "!search!"
)
echo(


setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
echo(
echo(
echo Now try with delayed expansion enabled
echo -----------------------------------------
echo(

:: Even though delayed expansion is enabled within the batch script, it is still disabled
:: within the pipe, so we still have to explicitly enable it via CMD /V:ON.
:: But now we must prevent expansion of the variables while in the batch context.
:: You have two options:

:: 1) Escape the !. The escape syntax changes depending on whether it is inside quotes or not:
echo Escape test:
if 1==1 (
  cmd /v:on /c echo ^^!text^^!|cmd /v:on /c findstr "^!search^!"
)
echo(

:: 2) Enclose both sides of the pipe within parentheses (very weird, but it works)
echo Parentheses test:
if 1==1 (
  (cmd /v:on /c echo !text!)|(cmd /v:on /c findstr "!search!")
)
```

--OUTPUT--

```
text=%SOME_VAR%;C:\Windows\system32...................etc
search=%SOME_VAR%


Starting with delayed expansion disabled
-----------------------------------------

Test when SOME_VAR is undefined:
%SOME_VAR%;C:\Windows\system32...................etc

Test when SOME_VAR is defined:
%SOME_VAR%;C:\Windows\system32...................etc



Now try with delayed expansion enabled
-----------------------------------------

Escape test:
%SOME_VAR%;C:\Windows\system32...................etc

Parentheses test:
%SOME_VAR%;C:\Windows\system32...................etc
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a very clear explanation and it works...

But how can I do this when it's a variable I'm echoing, with a value such as `%SOME_VAR%;`. I cannot build the string I'm searching into and add carets to it.

Comment: Obviously a good answer, but I can't see the reason to use cmd /v:on here. Why not simply use `echo %%text%% | findstr "%%search%%"`? As it seems that's all about normal variable names with percents. Then the percent expansion is also safe

Comment: @jeb - Doh! You are correct about the right side. I needlessly complicated the search bit. But the left side deals with the registry PATH value, and it may have content that is unsafe with normal expansion.

Comment: @dbenham - Yep, I haven't used/needed `cmd /v:on` on the right side when I commented above. My final line is `cmd /v:on /c Echo ^^!text^^!|FindStr /r /C:"^.*%%SOME_VAR%%;.*$" >NUL`